# Does `mount` have an option to create the mountpoint automatically if it doesn't already exist

Tags: linux, mount

Of course I could simply wrap mount in a script with `mkdir -p` before, but I was simply wondering if an ad hoc option already existed for that, since it would spare me having to make a symlink + script on every system I touch (which are a lot).

I have searched both in the manpage and on stachexchange, but I find it very difficult to find relevant threads, considering "automatically" and "mountpoint" etc... returns a lot of unrelated results.

Comment: If it were me, I'd consider creating a `function` in my `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Seamus as explained, the whole point is to not have to create a new unit of config on every single server I use.

Comment: OK - well good luck then, but you should consider using terms that have definitions as your requirements don't seem clear to me; e.g. "unit of configuration"? No reply necessary - just fyi.

Answer (score 4):

Such an option exists:

```
mount -o X-mount.mkdir ...
```

From the mount man page:

**X-mount.mkdir[=mode]**

> Allow to make a target directory (mountpoint) if it does not exit yet.  The optional argument mode specifies the filesystem access mode used for mkdir(2) in octal notation.  The default mode is 0755.  This functionality is supported **only** for root users or when mount executed **without** suid permissions. The option is also supported as x-mount.mkdir, this notation is deprecated since v2.30.